# Почему один код выдает "Значение типа char(*)[4] нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа char**", а другой работает?

Tags: c++

Вопрос такой, почему один код выдает "Значение типа char(*)[4] нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа char**"

```
char a[] = "abc";
char** cpp = &a;
```

а другой код проходит

```
char a[] = "abc";
char* cp = a;
char** cpp = &cp;
```

И подвопрос - круглые скобки в char(*)[4] играют какую-то роль?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, `char* cp = a` является сокращением для `char* cp = &a[0]`

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Ответы "Slav9n92", "AR Hovsepyan" и замечание "AnT" как раз указали на некоторые моменты, которые и дали понимание в моем вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором случае вы сначала делаете указатель, а потом указатель на указатель. `char* cp=a`; в принципе равносильно `char* cp=&a[0]`; Собственно именно по этому первый вариант не работает. Круглые скобки показывают нам, что это указатель на массив чаров.

Comment: "Собственно именно по этому первый вариант не работает." - увы, не понял почему так:(
Я так понимаю, что когда компилятор видит `a`, то он это истолковывает как `&a[0]`. Как Вы и сказали, `char* cp=a` он воспринимает как `char* cp=&a[0]` и соответственно вопросов по типам нету.
Но по идеи он и тут должен воспринимать `char** cpp = &a;` как `char** cpp = &&a[0];` т.е. адрес адреса для нулевого элемента, который есть `char`. Соответственно и эта надпись должна работать.

Comment: По логике так и должно быть, только вот нельзя написать & & а[0]. работать такая штука не будет, нужен промежуточный объект в виде уазателя, как во втором случае

Comment: Если написать & & то вы будете пытаться взять адрес от адреса, что не верно. Но если вы сначала присвоете его указателю и потом сделаете еще один &, то возмете адрес указателя что будет являтся указателем на указатель

Comment: Slav9n92 - Спасибо большое! Вроде разобрался, где я был не прав и чего не понимал:)

Answer (score 3):

В языке С++ переменную типа `T` можно инициализировать только значением типа `T` или значением, неявно приводимым к типу `T`.

Значение `&a` имеет тип `char (*)[4]` и *не может* быть использовано для инициализации указателя типа `char **`. Это разные, неприводимые типы, никакого отношения друг к другу не имеющие.

Значение `&cp` имеет тип `char **` и  *может* быть использовано для инициализации указателя типа `char **`. Это одинаковые типы

Вот и все. Вам компилятор все подробно расписал.

---

Скобки в `char (*)[4]` роль *играют*. `char (*)[4]` и `char *[4]` - разные типы.

Comment: "Значение `&a` имеет тип `char (*)[4]` и не может быть использовано для инициализации указателя типа `char **`" - можете пояснить, почему `&a` имеет такой тип (`char (*)[4]`). Я рассуждаю так - когда компилятор видит имя массива он его интерпретирует как адрес нулевого элемента т.е. `a` ~ `&a[0]`. Соответственно `&a` он должен интерпретировать как `&&a[0]`. Где я не прав?)

Comment: Массив выступает в роли указателя во всех контекстах **кроме**: 1. Унарный оператор `&`, 2) Оператор `sizeof`, 3) Строковый литерал, использованный для инициализации массива символов, 4) Оператор `_Alignof`. У вас как раз первый случай. Поэтому нет, компилятор НЕ интерпретирует его как адрес нулевого элемента.

Comment: Спасибо, этой информации и не доставало мне.

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то, что в некоторых случаях массив может быть интерпретирован компилятором как адрес своего первого элемента - он не является адресом первого элемента.

На рисунке ниже показан массив `a` и указатель на его первый элемент `cp`:

[image]

Когда вы пишете `&a` - вы получаете указатель на массив. Когда вы пишете `&cp` - вы получаете указатель на указатель. Массив не является указателем, поэтому эти два типа неприводимы друг к другу.

Comment: Спасибо!
Можете еще пояснить, в чем тогда разница между указателем на нулевой элемент массива и самим массивом. Не в первый раз встречаю, что "массив эквивалентен адресу своего первого элемента, но это ни одно и тоже". Т.е. в чем эквивалентен, на сколько они взаимозаменяемы, и в каких случаях это разные вещи?

Comment: @Дмитрий см. картинку

Comment: А можете её пожалуйста немного прокомментировать:)
из `&cp` идет стрелка к `cp` т.е. из адреса указателя мы получаем указатель?) У меня просто в голове иная картинка и тяжело их 2 сопоставить...

Comment: @Дмитрий `&cp` - это указатель на `cp`. Как ни странно, но указатель на `cp` указывает на `cp` - что я и показал стрелкой. На диаграмме нет никакого отношения "мы получаем".

Comment: "указатель на `cp` указывает на `cp`" путаюсь все-же немного - это работает, если стрелку воспринимать как знак равенства с разыменованием (`cp = *&cp`). Но в таком случае отношение `cp` и `a` не совсем улавливаю.

Comment: @Дмитрий стрелка - это отношение *"указывает на"*. Указатель `cp` указывает на первый элемент массива `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Массив такой же обьект, как и все остальные. Массив содержит в себе некоторое количество обьектов одного типа. Его имя используется точно также, как  и адрес его первого элемента, что дает возможность передать массив по ссыльке, а это означает, что при определении:

```
char* cp = a;
```

указатель    `cp`  указывает на первый элемент массива, или, другими словами, содержит адрес первого элемента массива. Когда известен адрес первого элемента, есть возможность работать со всей последовательностью...

Но `&a` это адрес `обьекта_массива` имеющий тип `char(*)[4]`, т.е. указатель на массив символов с четыремя элеметами типа `char`, а не указатель на адрес обьекта типа `char`(указатель на указатель). Точно также можно написать:

```
std::vector<char> a;
char* pv = &a[0]; // адрес первого элемента последовательности
char** pp = &pv;  // адрес указателья
```

Но нельзя:

```
char** ppv = &a;
```

поскольку `&a` это  `std::vector<char>*`, и никак не может преобразиться в    `char**`. P.S.  Разница только в том, что имя вектора не интерпретируется как адрес первого элемента посдеовательности